# unable return data from promise to other component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have an api posting data on server and i want to get that response in other file.
this is a function in `action.js` file. I want to return response of this promise to other component where it is called.

```
export const saveOrder = data => dispatch => {
  fetch(`${baseUrl}/save-order`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    body: data,
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log('json1', json);
     **want to return this json variable**
      alert('order placed');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error in saving', error);
    });
};
```

this is my component where i want to get its response when order is successfully placed. I have tried async and await but it did not worked.

```
  const postOrder = () => {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('userId', state.user.id);
    dispatch(saveOrder(data));
  };
```

Comment: Why does `saveOrder` return a `dispatch => {…}` function that never uses `dispatch`?

Comment: You cannot return the data from the function. You can at best return a promise for the data - the other component will then have to wait for the result, using either `.then()` or `await`. There's no way around this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using redux for state management. However, you are not using the dispatch function to store the data received in saveOrder. Actually, all that your dispatch does is just call the necessary thunk, and already in it you must call dispatch with an action that will store the data in the store. Then directly in the component itself using selector you can get the data from the store when they are available.
In general, you are using redux-thunk only to run an api request and not following the necessary concepts.
You can see the usage model here:
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic

Comment: I've tried by adding to store also.. but data in store will be saved like this
` {    "status": 200,    "message": "Order placed successfully"}` and i have to run a function in postOrder file only if status is true.. but it gives error because status does not exist at start because state is empty

Comment: @MuhammadMuaz What exactly do you want to do? Just show a notification? Perhaps it makes sense to do this directly inside the thunk function?

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to try passing the Dispatch function as parameter?

Just in case your Redux-Saga has problems?

The way I would create this function would a bit different, separating the roles.

```
const saveOrder = data => {

  return fetch(`${baseUrl}/save-order`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    body: data,
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      return "Success"
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return "Error"
    });
};


  
   saveOrder("any data")
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log(error.message))
 

    /*Instead of console.log you can place your dispatcher*/
```